# Selectize.js can't get dropdown to pop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Selectized select which is not showing a popup with the options, even though I can see in the debugger that the selectized control contains the desired options.  When I click on the dropdown button, the arrow points upwards as it would when displaying the list, but that is all that its doing and no popup containing the options list is displayed.  Also this dropdown is inside a bootstrap modal dialog.  The following code snippet shows the Selectize dropdown initialization and selectization.  The first part initializes the control.

[image]

the following loads the options array:

[image]

This is where the selectization occurs.  First we call the initialization method to load the options, and then use the resulting instantiated control to create the selectized Control:

[image]

By the way, I have the same exact code working on another page, but I just don't see why it wouldn't work in this page. The code is identical in both cases.

Code in text format:

```
var sgAllSelectize = [];

var pplicationId = null;

function bindAllSGContainer(appId, option) {
    /* ok, so we loaded the SG select element, time to selectize it */
    var handler;
    var pageType = $("#hdnPageType").val();
    if (pageType == 'clone') {
        handler = onChangeSGidForAllServer;
    }
    if (pageType == 'migration') {
        handler = onChangeMigrationSGidForAllServer;
    }
    if (pageType == 'failover') {
        handler = onChangeFailoverSGidForAllServer;
    }

    var element = "#allServerSGselect_" + appId;
    applicationId = appId;

    var $vs = $(element).selectize({
        create: true,
        sortField: 'text',
        placeHolder: 'Example: sg-00000000',
        persist: false,
        options: option,
        createOnBlur: true,
        allowEmptyOption: false,
        closeAfterSelect: true,
        onChange: function (input) {
            var aid = appId;
            var sgValid = input.search(/^sg-[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$/i);
            var sg_selection = $("option", element);
            var sg_selection_stripped = sg_selection.val().slice(0, 11);
            if (sgValid == 0) {
                sg_selection.val(sg_selection_stripped);
                handler(input, aid);
            } else {
                console.log("sg " + input + " is not valid");
                this.removeOption(input, "silent");
                this.setValue("");
                /* sending an empty sg id will disable the sg elements */
                handler("", aid);
            }
        }
    });
    sgAllSelectize[appId] = $vs;
}


var allOptsArray = [];

//load up the options into an object array
for (var h = 0; h < str1.length; h++) {
    optAllSgObject = new Object(); 
    optAllSgObject.text = str1[h];
    optAllSgObject.value = str1[h];
    allOptsArray.push(optAllSgObject);
}
    bindAllSGContainer(appId, allOptsArray);
    var o = sgAllSelectize[appId];
    selectizeAll = o[0].selectize;
```

Comment: Please don't post image of the code, but the code itself

Comment: Sorry about that, I just didn't know how to get it formatted correctly.  I'm kind of new at this.  Also in the first line that should be "..with.." rather than "...which.."

Comment: You can post your code and use the markdown button accordingly to format your code see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: How can I re-edit this?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know enough about this control that can help here?

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, the problem was because the selectized control was inside a table cell which had overflow: hide for style.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hidden in a comment.

The surrounding cell or table had an overflow: hidden.  Ensure this is set to overflow: visible.